# Best Practices: including a 'Sign in with Twitter' Button (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, twitter

I am trying to incorporate an option for users to 'Sign in with Twitter' in my Android app. I looked through the [Twitter API Docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs) and found [the page that describes signing in with Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/sign-twitter), which just says to,

*Place a button on your site or application which allows Twitter users to enjoy the benefits of a registered user account in as little as one click.*

I was trying to find a widget like this:

[image: Sign in with Twitter button]

- Is there anything like the View `com.facebook.widget.LoginButton` for
  Twitter?
- Is the common solution to just create a button and download the
  Twitter logo, font, etc.?

**Edit:**

What is the best resource for downloading the twitter icons, colors etc. for Android?

Do I have to create my own widget?

Comment: You could simply set the background of the button to the image you've posted if you want using `android:background="@drawable/twitter_login_button"` in the XML (just save the image in your drawable folder first and call it twitter_login_button)

Comment: @user184994 That doesn't seem like a good solution. It wouldn't scale well. What if the user didn't speak English? What if I wanted to change 'Sign in' to 'Log in'? I would have to create a lot of drawables for each possible scenario.

Answer (score 0):

too late to answer, but i see still there is no answer hence answering,

You can use com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton with twittersdk or consider using custom buttons like mentioned here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27275945/896340)