# Using custom login button with Twitter Fabric?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I have been trying to use a normal button to execute the authentication process with the twitter sdk but it does not seem to work. Anyone have tried anything similar?

- I have correctly setup the API keys, etc..
- The login process execute correctly but the callback part seems not to be called.
- None of my logs are executed (Neither the success or failure part)

The code

```
buttonTwitterLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Twitter.logIn(LoginActivity1.this, new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult) {
                Log.i(TAG, "success");
                Log.i(TAG, twitterSessionResult.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "failed");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: just a suggestion, check whether your time is set to automatic or not

Comment: It is on automatic. Correct date and different timezone than I use (set by myself)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Luis from Developer Relations team at Twitter. Fabric will support theming on the future, meanwhile you can customize the button by creating a custom view that inherits from `TwitterLoginButton`.

Cannonball sample app implements a custom button:

```
public class CannonballTwitterLoginButton extends TwitterLoginButton {
    public CannonballTwitterLoginButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CannonballTwitterLoginButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CannonballTwitterLoginButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (isInEditMode()){
            return;
        }
        setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable
                .ic_signin_twitter), null, null, null);
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sign_up_button);
        setTextSize(20);
        setPadding(30, 0, 10, 0);
        setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tw__blue_default));
        setTypeface(App.getInstance().getTypeface());
    }
}
```

https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/fabric/samples/cannonball/view/CannonballTwitterLoginButton.java

Layout file:

```
<io.fabric.samples.cannonball.view.CannonballTwitterLoginButton
    android:id="@+id/twitter_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/sign_up_button"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_button_margin_top"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_button_margin_bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/login_button_margin_start"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/login_button_margin_start"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/login_button_margin_end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/login_button_margin_end"
    android:text="@string/sign_in_with_twitter"
    android:textColor="@color/grayish_blue"
    android:textSize="@dimen/login_button_text_size"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-android/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_login.xml

Callback setup:

```
private void setUpTwitterButton() {
    twitterButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_button);
    twitterButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            SessionRecorder.recordSessionActive("Login: twitter account active", result.data);
            startThemeChooser();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.toast_twitter_signin_fail),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Crashlytics.logException(exception);
        }
    });
}
```

https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/fabric/samples/cannonball/activity/LoginActivity.java

I strongly recommend you to clone the code and take a look on it.

Comment: I want to get username and profile picture of the user after user is logged in successfully, ca you please help?

Answer (score 103):

You can achieve this by using `TwitterAuthClient`. i.e,

First of all create normal button like,

```
<Button
      android:id:"@+id/twitter_custom_button"
      ...  />
```

Now, in you java class file use `TwitterAuthClient` instead of `TwitterLoginButton`. then set your `CallBack` inside `Button`'s `onClick`

```
TwitterAuthClient mTwitterAuthClient= new TwitterAuthClient();

Button twitter_custom_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twitter_custom_button);
twitter_custom_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


             mTwitterAuthClient.authorize(this, new com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback<TwitterSession>() {

                       @Override
                       public void success(Result<TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult) {
                           // Success
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
            });


        }
});



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
    mTwitterAuthClient.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
}
```

Comment: The `onActivityResult` call is KEY, I forgot to add that and this helped me.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks exact solution.

Answer (score 44):

Well actually there's a way of doing this

```
 private TwitterAuthClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
    client = new TwitterAuthClient();


    Button customLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.custom_twitter_login);
    customLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            client.authorize(LoginActivity.this, new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Result<TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    client.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Be aware, onActivityResult part is very important, you seem to lost it.

here's my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/custom_twitter_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:text="@string/twitter_login"/>
```

Comment: This should be correct answer. This is the only one that answers the question. The question was not "how do I theme the login button?" The question is "how do I NOT USE the login button". This is the right way to do it.

Comment: perfect answer...helping me...ty

Answer (score 31):

Since Fabric doesn't allow theming yet, we should assume that we'll have to write potentially throw away code to get this to work.  As such, I prefer less code to more code when I know I won't be keeping it.

Luis's solution will work fine, but my UI was done, with a button already, and I just wanted that button to work.  Here's how I accomplished this.

Drop in the TwitterLoginButton, as requested by the Fabric wizard, but set it to visibility: gone

```
 <com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
    android:id="@+id/twitter_login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Pull the reference of the loginButton in your Activity (also part of Fabric setup - nothing new here):

```
loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);
```

Finally, for my existing button, I added a click listener, which simply delegated the click event over to the twitter login button.

```
myLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loginButton.performClick();
        }
    });
```

Worked like a charm.

Comment: It's not a solution , but it's really great tricks. It worked my code. Thanks a lot for this valuable solution. :)

Comment: This is a hack.

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani Indeed. Working around inflexible libraries often involves hacks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also avoid creating a CustomTwitterLoginButton class by doing the default implementation of the twitter login button and then doing this:

```
twitterLoginButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
    twitterLoginButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_twitter);
    twitterLoginButton.setCompoundDrawablePadding(0);
    twitterLoginButton.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    twitterLoginButton.setText("Login with Twitter");
    twitterLoginButton.setTextSize(18);
```